# Mobile website html5 with back end java?

Tags: java, javascript, php, html, postgresql

I am new to html5 but i know Java, c#, c++ pretty well.

I need to make a simple ordering type website for school. My professor suggested using html5. I need this website to run on all phones, ipad, laptops (will create mobile version as well). The issue is, I need to connect to postgresql(or some other same type of database) to store my items and orders. When people generally make websites using html5, what do they use for the back end logic? can't I use java? I was thinking to use netbeans as my IDE.

I have very confused because when I search on google, it seems like all tutorials are using html5, php , javascript. I have no knowledge of php. I would rather use Java since I already know it.

Please suggest some ideas/tutorials. Thanks!

Comment: Fairly subjective question... You have already researched it (obviously) and it has provided you with an answer. Just because you don't like their answer (because you don't know how to use php), doesn't mean you should come on here and ask for an alternative. Perhaps you should learn php, as it appears to be a fundamental in what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes, you can develop server-sided web applications in Java. Google for "Servlet" or "JSP".

Comment: well there is JavaServer Pages, nerver used it, no idea how, but if you insist on not using php there are only so many options......

Comment: Yes, you can use java for the backend. Beware that the question will be likely soon closed for being off topic (which does not mean it would necessarily be a bad question, just that it does not belong to SO).

Comment: You need to understand better the concepts. HTML is client side and Java, PHP are server side. You can use any language server side, just search how to use it.

Comment: You have almost too many choices... Think whether you want to do single-page application or multi-page application.

Comment: may be you can take a look at [link](https://netbeans.org/features/html5/)

Comment: i"ll look into php. If it seems confusing I can always switch to java. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I have never tried to build the back end for a website using c# or c++ so I can't give you any advice with these languages.  However, I have built websites in Java, and have tried many different frameworks.

I recommend that you try Play Framework.  You should use version 1, not version 2 as it is simpler to pick up and get going with.  Version 2 is more powerful and will be worth learning, but not if you are building a simple website.  I like Play version 1 for the following reasons:

- Instant compilation - Save the Java you are working on and refresh your web page.  In the background it compiles any file changes and you see the result.  This can be switched off for production.
- MVC - there is a clear separation
- Documentation - The documentation is very clear and useful

More information:  http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/home